# Editable row in react table using Ant Design UI

Tags: reactjs, antd

Hello guys I am new to react js. I need some help.

I want a 3x3 of react js table. 1st row should contain the title of the table with a checkbox. If the header of the title checked then only it's the corresponding columns should editable else it is disabled. How can I achieve this? And one thing I should allow to use only `Ant Design`.

Please, someone, help out.

Comment: If you want to get some help you need to provide details about what you tried so far, what is preventing you to achieve this, provide a sandbox and ask a clear and salvageable question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a free code delivery platform.

Comment: @Florian here is the sandbox link.https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-curie-lyovv?file=/index.js 

In that link, I want the bottom toggle button with the title of the table. That is enough. Decibel and all other staff are I will check it later. Now please place that switch with the title.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **components** attribute on Table component (https://ant.design/components/table/#API), and override header cells using a custom component which includes the switch :

```
<Table
  components={{
    header: {
      cell: <YourCustomComponentForHeaderCellWhichIncludesSwitch />
    }
  }}
/>
```

See also https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/1c85bb3b6231a01c53c53204846a03c4cfdf41f9/components/table/interface.tsx#L39.

Comment: Thank You. I will check that.